# The query is getting slow when a CASE statement in Having a clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

Below query is getting slower as I have used the **case statement in having clause** and the data is very huge, so below query is taking time for fetching the such huge data for overcoming this I need some **alternatiive solution** instead of the Having clause with case statement.

Explanation about the query,

I need to fetch the data by some types with condtions like I have three types 
**Flat Amount(1), Flat amount of rent(2) and percentage of rent(3)** on that basis I need to do the **SUM of the charges** with condtions like if type is 2 then fetch the record with charge type is 2 and charge code is 3 like that. Please look into the below query and suggest me alternative solution is there,

```
SELECT
     n.id,
     ro.id,
     n.notice_amount,
     n.notice_type_id,
     SUM ( c.charge_amount ) AS charge_amount
 FROM
     notification n
     JOIN notification_doc_groups ndg ON ( ndg.notice_id = n.id AND ndg.is_published = TRUE )
     JOIN properties p ON ( p.id = ndg.property_id )
     JOIN customer_details cd ON ( cd.notification_id = n.id )
     JOIN rent_out ro ON ( ro.property_id = p.id )
     JOIN charges c ON ( c.rent_out_id = ro.id )
 WHERE
     ( ( n.notice_type_id = 1
     AND c.charge_amount > 0
     AND c.charge_type_id = 2 )
     OR ( n.notice_type_id = 2
     AND c.charge_type_id = 2
     AND c.charge_code = 3 )
     OR ( n.notice_type_id = 3
     AND c.scheduled_id IS NOT NULL ) )
 GROUP BY
     n.id,
     ro.id,
     n.notice_type_id,
     n.notice_amount
 HAVING
     CASE
       WHEN n.notice_type_id = 1 THEN ( ( sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= n.notice_amount ) )
       WHEN n.notice_type_id = 2 THEN sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= sum ( c.charge_amount ) * ( n.notice_amount / 100 ) -- or(  )
       WHEN n.notice_type_id = 3 THEN sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= sum ( c.charge_amount ) * ( n.notice_amount / 100 )
     END;
```

Thanks

Comment: You usually SELECT the same columns as you GROUP BY, but here ro.id isn't selected. Any special reason?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Please don't tag a question with tags that do not apply (mysql). Move the case to the list if columns, and use an alias. Change it so that when the condition is met, it returns 1, for false 0, then test the alias in the having clause for 1.

Comment: vat is another table?

Comment: Yes I'm using the postgreSQL. removed the mySql tag. By mistakenly added the vat corrected it.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Are you implying that the query without the `HAVING` clause runs faster?  I don't believe believe that.  I think the issue is simply that this is a complicated query and that the database may not be set up well for the joins and filters.

Comment: @Gordan Yes, actually I have checked the performance of the query so it is taking near about 4 to 5 seconds to fetch the 30 records and having clause with conditions it is slowing the query and I have also added the conditions on where clause too as per the type. I need some alternate solution for this.

Comment: are the references to `dp.notice_type_id` in the where clause supposed to be `n.notice_type_id` ?

Comment: @Gary Sorry, corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate out the three different cases and use a union to join them.   It shouldn't make a difference in the results but might make it easier for the optimizer.  If nothing else you'll be able to run each separate notice type and see if one is causing the slowdown.

I am a bit confused about the condition on notice types 2 and 3 though:

```
sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= sum ( c.charge_amount ) * ( n.notice_amount / 100 )
```

It looks like you don't need to check the charge amount at all, you can just find entries where the notice_amount is 100 or less.

```
SELECT
     n.id,
     ro.id,
     n.notice_amount,
     n.notice_type_id,
     SUM ( c.charge_amount ) AS charge_amount
 FROM
     notification n
     JOIN notification_doc_groups ndg ON ( ndg.notice_id = n.id AND ndg.is_published = TRUE )
     JOIN properties p ON ( p.id = ndg.property_id )
     JOIN rent_out ro ON ( ro.property_id = p.id )
     JOIN charges c ON ( c.rent_out_id = ro.id )
 WHERE
     n.notice_type_id = 3 AND c.scheduled_id IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY
     n.id,
     ro.id,
     n.notice_type_id,
     n.notice_amount
 HAVING
     sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= sum ( c.charge_amount ) * ( n.notice_amount / 100 )
UNION ALL
SELECT
     n.id,
     ro.id,
     n.notice_amount,
     n.notice_type_id,
     SUM ( c.charge_amount ) AS charge_amount
 FROM
     notification n
     JOIN notification_doc_groups ndg ON ( ndg.notice_id = n.id AND ndg.is_published = TRUE )
     JOIN properties p ON ( p.id = ndg.property_id )
     JOIN rent_out ro ON ( ro.property_id = p.id )
     JOIN charges c ON ( c.rent_out_id = ro.id )
 WHERE
     n.notice_type_id = 2 AND c.charge_type_id = 2
 GROUP BY
     n.id,
     ro.id,
     n.notice_type_id,
     n.notice_amount
 HAVING
     sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= sum ( c.charge_amount ) * ( n.notice_amount / 100 )
UNION ALL
SELECT
     n.id,
     ro.id,
     n.notice_amount,
     n.notice_type_id,
     SUM ( c.charge_amount ) AS charge_amount
 FROM
     notification n
     JOIN notification_doc_groups ndg ON ( ndg.notice_id = n.id AND ndg.is_published = TRUE )
     JOIN properties p ON ( p.id = ndg.property_id )
     JOIN rent_out ro ON ( ro.property_id = p.id )
     JOIN charges c ON ( c.rent_out_id = ro.id )
 WHERE
     n.notice_type_id = 1 AND c.charge_amount > 0 AND c.charge_type_id = 2
 GROUP BY
     n.id,
     ro.id,
     n.notice_type_id,
     n.notice_amount
 HAVING
     sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= n.notice_amount
```

Comment: Thanks Gary for your solution. I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
HAVING   (n.notice_type_id = 1 AND  sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= n.notice_amount) 
      OR (  n.notice_type_id IN (2,3) AND n.notice_amount / 100 >=1)
```

Comment: I have already used above one, but it is also getting slow because here also we are checking the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that the planner can't optimize for the case so try an array:

```
having (array[
   sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= n.notice_amount,
   sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= sum ( c.charge_amount ) * ( n.notice_amount / 100 ),
   sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= sum ( c.charge_amount ) * ( n.notice_amount / 100 )
]::bool[])[n.notice_type_id]
```

Comment: I will try your solution and let you know. Thanks

Comment: But how can I add the types into that array.

Comment: @NileshWani I don't undernstand. What types? I turned the `case` into an `array`.

Comment: This types mentioned in query WHEN n.notice_type_id = 1 THEN do this ( ( sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= n.notice_amount ) ), if n.notice_type_id = 1 then do this THEN sum ( c.charge_amount ) >= sum ( c.charge_amount ) * ( n.notice_amount / 100 )

Comment: How can I add that type and on that basis do the calculation.

Comment: @NileshWani The type is the index of the array. Depending on the type value the corresponding array element will be the result of the expression. Just use it as posted.